# ssh to computer including path does not work

Tags: ssh, rsync

When I use `ssh username@IP`  it works, and then I can use  `cd`  to navigate to  `/path/dir`

When I use `ssh username@IP:/path/dir`  it does not work.

The error message is:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname IP:/path/dir: Name or service not known
```

How can I get `ssh username@IP:/path/dir` to open in the desired directory?

I need this to work with `rsync` through as ssh tunnel to a specific directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### **SSH AND COMMAND**

> How can I get ssh username@IP:/path/dir to open in the desired directory?

If you want to `ssh` into a given path you can use:

```
ssh USER@SERVER -t "cd /path/dir; bash --login"
```

or

```
ssh -i /PathToKey -p PORT USER@SERVER -t "cd /path/dir; bash --login"
```

or

```
ssh -i /PathToKey -p PORT USER@SERVER -t "cd /path/dir; $SHELL --login"
```

- `-i` if you use public-key authentication
- `-p` if you have set a port in sshd_config
- `-t` keeps up the connection for user interaction
- the `"command"` is in quotes
- **COMMAND 1+2** | `bash --login` is required to keep up the connection after the `cd` and start `bash`
- **COMMAND 3** | `$SHELL --login` is required to keep up the connection after the `cd` and starts user's preferred `shell` program

#### **RSYNC OVER SSH**

> I need this to work to rsync through as ssh tunnel to a specific directory.

Will you run `rsync` on the remote machine itself?

Run `rsync` after `ssh` on the remote machine but for what you need `cd` into path?

If you want to run `rsync` from local to remote or from remote to local machine.

> The general syntax for transferring files with `rsync` is as follows:

```
Local to Remote: rsync [OPTION]... -e ssh [SRC]... [USER@]HOST:DEST
```

```
Remote to Local: rsync [OPTION]... -e ssh [USER@]HOST:SRC... [DEST]
```

From `local to remote`:

```
rsync -a /localpath/file user@server:/remotepath/
```

From `remote to local`:

```
rsync -a user@server:/remotepath/file /localpath/
```

[How to Transfer Files with Rsync over SSH](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-transfer-files-with-rsync-over-ssh/)

#### **FUSE/SSHFS:**

Use `sshfs/fuse` to mount the remote path on your local machine
and use `rsync` or `cp` on your local machine

[HOW TO USE SSHFS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SSHFS)

#### **SCP**

Use `scp` to **copy/transfer** `remote to local` or `local to remote`

`scp [OPTION] [user@]SRC_HOST:]file1 [user@]DEST_HOST:]file2`

[How to Use SCP Command to Securely Transfer Files](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-scp-command-to-securely-transfer-files/)

***I personally use and prefer fuse/sshfs***

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get `ssh username@IP:/path/dir` to open in the desired directory?

Not at all. `ssh` is a remote shell access method and network forwarding tool; it doesn't "open a directory" or something similar. 
You seem to be confusing it with `scp` or `rsync`. `ssh` itself has no syntax to change working directory like you intend to, here.

However,

> I need this to work to `rsync` through as ssh tunnel to a specific directory.

That makes no sense, `rsync` doesn't care about the working directory of whatever `ssh` runs on the server side. Tunnelling `rsync` just means tunneling network packets.

So, what you want to do is not necessary nor helpful.